# ROW type/constructor in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Does BigQuery have the concept of a `ROW`, for example, similar to [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-constructor-optimization.html) or [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) or [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions014.htm#SQLRF52074) or [Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/values.html)? I know it sort of implicitly uses it when doing an `INSERT ... VALUES (...)` , for example:

```
INSERT dataset.Inventory (product, quantity)
VALUES('top load washer', 10),
      ('front load washer', 20)
```

Each of the values would be implicitly be a `ROW` type of the `Inventory` table, but is this construction allowed elsewhere in BigQuery? Or is this a feature that doesn't exist in BQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below is a simplest / naïve example of such constructor in BigQuery

```
with t1 as (
  select 'top load washer' product, 10 quantity, 'a' type, 'x' category union all
  select 'front load washer', 20, 'b', 'y' 
), t2 as (
  select 1 id, 'a' code, 'x' value union all
  select 2, 'd', 'z'
)
select *
from t1
where (type, category) = (select as struct code, value from t2 where id = 1)
```

Besides using in simple queries, it can also be use in BQ scripts - for example (another simplistic example)

```
declare type, category string;
create temp table t2 as (
  select 1 id, 'a' code, 'x' value union all
  select 2, 'd', 'z'
);    
set (type, category) = (select as struct code, value from t2 where id = 1);
```

Comment: thanks, is there any more information on `DECLARE TYPE`? All I can find about it is as a side note here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#parameterized_data_types.

Comment: also, if I'm understanding correctly, the `STRUCT` in BigQuery query acts almost like the ROW constructor ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#declare

Comment: `if I'm understanding correctly, the STRUCT in BigQuery query acts almost like the ROW constructor` that was exactly the point I had in mind :o)